# Multiple databases vs partitioning in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, partitioning, sharding, scalability

Consider following database schema for *PostgreSQL* (I'm using 13.x.x)
[image: my current database structure]

**Users table** - just place to store users and do authentication

**Projects** - projects which are created by specific user

**Driver/Event/Vehicle types** - "handbook" tables defined in specific project (e.g. project#1 could have only 10 vehicle types, but project#2 - 1000)

**Really big table** - 30 up to 70 million rows **per specific project**

**Event reactions** - abstraction around "really big table" (the number of rows could as big)

I do want to partition driver/event/vehicle/really_big_data/event_reactions by *project_id* field which could give me something like this:

```
driver_types_some_uuid1
driver_types_some_uuid2
...
event_types_some_uuid1
event_types_some_uuid2
...
really_big_data_some_uuid1
really_big_data_some_uuid2
...
and etc.
```

The reason why I do want to make partitions is to make faster search per project in my API, easier way to locate data visually and users want have to "backup" theirs projects as some kind of dump.

But I have some feelings that this is a bad way, since I'll face foreign keys between partitioned tables and this is not easy as I know so far.

So I came up with next idea:

- Create database "A" for users and their projects lists
  [image: database to store users and projects]
- Create databases named *database_project_id" per project
  [image: database per project (1)]
  [image: database per project (2)]

and etc.
As I see now, I could easily select data per project, do dumps, visually locate data without headache. But this leads me to creating some abstractions in my API code though: open 1 DB connection for users/projects and manage N-amount of DB connections for each "project", which are requested (if project is not requested for certain amount of time - close connection).

**So the question is**: Is my idea about creating databases instead of partitions any good? Are there better options to do it in such case?

**UPD** I do not need any relations between different users/projects.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Have you considered using different schemas within the same database?

Comment: Sounds potentially like a little premature optimization. I don't know all of the specifics of partitioning in PostgreSQL, but for the database systems I am familiar with it's not a feature for improving search performance on a table. The reasoning being is because partitioning is just a linear reduction in the amount of data, whereas B-Tree indexes results in a logarithmic reduction in the amount of data to search - which is a much smaller reduction comparatively. I say this having worked with tables that were in the 10s of billions of rows without partitioning and were very fast to search.

Comment: Follow up on my former comment, please take it only in regards to search performance. There are other benefits from a management perspective that developers do use the *multiple database for multiple tenants* design approach. So there is nothing necessarily wrong with doing that, from a management perspective, if it doesn't complicate the application layer. Just wanted to make it clear, it's not a design necessarily for improving search performance.

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні Interesting, by that we are free from using N-amount of connections to sifferent databases, right? Is that only one differences between N-schemas and N-databases?

Comment: @J.D. Thanks for response. I have not only search queries, but a lot of Inserts and possible "dump" downloads. That's why it seems for me easier to call "pg_dump" command on specific database without specifying additional flags (like -n, -t) for excluding/including tables/schemas. I think that it would be easier to do horizontal scaling also (just move specific database for user project to another virtual machine). But I'm not that mature in such stuff, that' why I think that I've picked very bad design and asking such questions :(

Comment: Gotcha! Sounds like you have some reasonable reasons from a management perspective then. That makes sense. Best of luck!